# Run query by regex on _id field in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a regex query in Elastic search based on a field called `_id`, but I'm getting this error:

> Can only use wildcard queries on keyword and text fields - not on
>   [_id] which is of type [_id]

I've tried `regexp`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "_id": {
                "value": "test-product-all-user_.*",
                "flags" : "ALL",
                "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and `wildcard`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "_id": {
                "value": "test-product-all-user_.*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But both threw the same error.

This is the complete error just in case:

> ```
> {   "error": {
>     "root_cause": [
>       {
>         "type": "query_shard_exception",
>         "reason": "Can only use wildcard queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]",
>         "index_uuid": "Cg0zrr6dRZeHJ8Jmvh5HMg",
>         "index": "explore_segments_v3"
>       }
>     ],
>     "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
>     "reason": "all shards failed",
>     "phase": "query",
>     "grouped": true,
>     "failed_shards": [
>       {
>         "shard": 0,
>         "index": "explore_segments_v3",
>         "node": "-ecTRBmnS2OgjHrrq6GCOw",
>         "reason": {
>           "type": "query_shard_exception",
>           "reason": "Can only use wildcard queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]",
>           "index_uuid": "Cg0zrr6dRZeHJ8Jmvh5HMg",
>           "index": "explore_segments_v3"
>         }
>       }
>     ]   },   "status": 400 }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

_id is a special kind of feild in Elasticsearch ,  It's not really an indexed field like other text fields, it's actually "generated" based on the UID of the document.

You can refer to this link for more information https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

As per the documentation it only supports limited type of queries (term, terms, match, query_string, simple_query_string), and if you want to do more advanced text search like wildcard or regexp you will need to index the ID into an actual text field on the document itself.